# how do I remove fab bottom padding in scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

widgets used as fab in a scaffold
seem to have padding by default

see [dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7e25e855887884403892974a2046522a&null_safety=true)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
          floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Container(height: 56, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

how do I remove the padding at the bottom of the red container?

the current (lame) workaround being

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
+         bottomSheet: Container(height: 16, color: Colors.red),
          floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Container(height: 56, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change floatingActionButton location:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: 
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat
```

to

```
floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

result:
[image]